# How to insert SP results in a multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an sp it results in 3 sets. Now the problem is i want insert these 3 result sets in to 3 temp tables. In these three results are different structures and no.of columns also different in these results.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server has no built-in mechanism for capturing multiple result sets returned from Stored Procedures where the result sets have differing numbers of columns and/or datatypes in the same column position. `INSERT...EXEC` can output multiple result sets, but they need to have the same number of columns with the same datatypes in each position. And both `OPENQUERY` and `OPENROWSET` will only return the first result set, no matter how many are returned by the stored procedure (or query).

However, this can be accomplished using SQLCLR. So, *if you can't update the Stored Procedure*, then you can do something like the following in .NET / C#:

```
using (SqlConnection _Connection = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString))
{
  using (SqlCommand _Command = _Connection.CreateCommand())
  {
    _Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    _Command.CommandText = "SchemaName.StoredProcedureName";
    // parameters, if any

    _Connection.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader _Reader = _Command.ExecuteReader())
    {
      // Stored Procedure has been executed. Now save the results.
      // Using the Context Connection allows access to local temp tables.

      using (SqlConnection _Connection2 = new SqlConnection("Context Connection = true;"))
      {
        using (SqlCommand _Command2 = _Connection2.CreateCommand())
        {
          _Connection2.Open();

          _Command2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO #Temp1 (column_list)
                 VALUES (@Param1, @Param2, ...);";

          SqlParameter _Param1 = new SqlParameter("Param1", SqlDbType.Int);
          _Command2.Parameters.Add(_Param1);

          // define addition parameters

          while (_Reader.Read())
          {
            _Param1.Value = _Reader.GetValue(0);
            _Param2.Value = _Reader.GetValue(1);
            // set additional parameters

            _Command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }

          _Reader.NextResult(); // move to result set #2

          _Command2.Parameters.Clear(); // reset input parameters
          _Command2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO #Temp2 (column_list2)
                 VALUES (@Param1, @Param2, ...);";

          SqlParameter _Param1 = new SqlParameter("Param1", SqlDbType.Int);
          _Command2.Parameters.Add(_Param1);

          // define addition parameters

          while (_Reader.Read())
          {
            _Param1.Value = _Reader.GetValue(0);
            _Param2.Value = _Reader.GetValue(1);
            // set additional parameters

            _Command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }

          _Reader.NextResult(); // move to result set #3

          _Command2.Parameters.Clear(); // reset input parameters
          _Command2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO #Temp3 (column_list3)
                 VALUES (@Param1, @Param2, ...);";

          SqlParameter _Param1 = new SqlParameter("Param1", SqlDbType.Int);
          _Command2.Parameters.Add(_Param1);

          // define addition parameters

          while (_Reader.Read())
          {
            _Param1.Value = _Reader.GetValue(0);
            _Param2.Value = _Reader.GetValue(1);
            // set additional parameters

            _Command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, since you want to store the results into local temporary tables, those need to be created *before* you execute this SQLCLR stored procedure. If you create them inside the SQLCLR stored procedure, they won't exist once the stored procedure completes.

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Temp1 (column1 DATATYPE_1, column2 DATATYPE_2, ...);
CREATE TABLE #Temp2 (column1 DATATYPE_1, column2 DATATYPE_2, ...);
CREATE TABLE #Temp3 (column1 DATATYPE_1, column2 DATATYPE_2, ...);

EXEC dbo.SQLCLR_StoredProcedure;

SELECT * FROM #Temp1;
SELECT * FROM #Temp2;
SELECT * FROM #Temp3;
```

---

BUT, as [@AndriyM](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/6965/andriy-m) pointed out in a comment on this answer, *if* you are able to modify the Stored Procedure, then given that the local temporary tables need to be created first anyway<sup>**</sup>, it would be better / simpler to modify your Stored Procedure to insert directly into the temp tables, as opposed to adding logic to control which single result set gets returned. In this case, you can detect the existence of the local temp tables and if they do exist, then insert into them, else return the result sets as the Stored Procedure currently does, and this will ensure that any existing code that calls this Stored Procedure will continue to get the three expected result sets. And you don't even need to add any optional input parameters. Just use the following approach per each of the three queries that returns a result set:

```sql
IF (OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Temp1') IS NULL)
BEGIN  -- Temp Table does NOT exist, so return result set
   SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3, ...
   FROM   SchemaName.TableName
   WHERE  ...
END;
ELSE
BEGIN  -- Temp Table DOES exist, so insert results into it
   INSERT INTO #Temp1 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
      SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3, ...
      FROM   SchemaName.TableName
      WHERE  ...
END;
```

<sup>**</sup> Creating the local temporary tables first wasn't necessarily specific to my SQLCLR suggestion. A single local temp table also needs to be created first in situations where one is able to use `INSERT...EXEC`. However, in situations where `OPENQUERY` is an option, then doing `SELECT...INTO #tmp` would allow for not creating the local temp table first.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have to create a single procedure to deal with three result sets, below is the solution. But as Aaron Bertrand have suggested in comments, if possible try having three different procedures for three different result set.

If three different SPs is not accepted due to complex logic or architectural limitation, then

1. Accept additional input parameter (like an integer with possible values 1,2,3)
2. If passed 1 in the input parameter, at the time of returning result return the first result set. If 2 in input parameter then return 2.
3. In main procedure, call this procedure thrice. Each time with different input parameter number (i.e. 1 , 2, 3).

Below is the sample

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sampleProc @ReturnType INT
AS
BEGIN
    -- Your logic here

    IF @ReturnType = 1
    BEGIN
         -- Return first result set
    END

    IF @ReturnType = 2
    BEGIN
         -- Return second result set
    END    

    IF @ReturnType = 3
    BEGIN
         -- Return third result set
    END
END
```

EDIT: One additional point. You have to very precise while making us the if logic over here. As the same procedure needs to be called thrice, if may have an performance impact depending on what logic you are trying to implement. If possible make use of the same if block to incorporate all logic for the specific return scenario and keep the generic part in the head.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your SP **always** returns 3 sets and you **always** need to parse all of them, one approach would be like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.YourSP
AS
BEGIN
    -- Your main logic here

    -- Try to get your SP to output the result like this:
    SELECT 'Set 1'
        ,'a'
        ,'b'
        ,'c'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'Set 2'
        ,'x'
        ,'y'
        ,NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'Set 3'
        ,'z'
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
END
```

Then you'll store the result on the first temp table that will contain a 'tag' field setId which will be used to put the data in your 'final' 3 temp tables:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
    setId VARCHAR(10)
    ,col1 VARCHAR(10)
    ,col2 VARCHAR(10)
    ,col3 VARCHAR(10)
    )
GO

INSERT INTO #temp
EXEC dbo.YourSP
GO

SELECT col1
    ,col2
    ,col3
INTO #t1
FROM #temp
WHERE setId = 'Set 1'

SELECT col1
    ,col2
INTO #t2
FROM #temp
WHERE setId = 'Set 2'

SELECT col1
INTO #t3
FROM #temp
WHERE setId = 'Set 3'
```

Depending on the workload and the size/type of your data, this may not be suited for your situation.
A better approach would be to use separate stored procs as Aaron Bertrand suggested, or even input parameters as mentioned by SwapnilBhate.

Comment: The `UNION ALL` could work in cases where the Stored Procedure can be updated _and_ the datatypes are in the same position for each query, but that probably won't work here since the O.P. seems to have indicated in the question that the datatypes are not the same for each position (or at least that is how I interpreted the "different structures" part of the question).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to run everything in T-SQL, here is a much simpler solution with PowerShell.

First, let's create test environment (I am running on my local default instance)

```
use TEMPDB;
go
-- create three temp tables to hold the returned results from SP
create table dbo.t1 (a varchar(30), d datetime);
create table dbo.t2 (id int, a varchar(30), b int);
create table dbo.t3 (a varchar(30), b int, d datetime);
go
-- now create the primary table
create table dbo.t (id int identity, a varchar(30), b int, d datetime default current_timestamp); 
go
-- populate the primary table with a few rows
insert into dbo.t (a, b, d)
values ('hello', 11, '2011-01-01'), ('world', 22, '2012-02-02'), ('good', 33, '2013-01-03'), ('morning', 44, '2014-04-04'), ('others', 55, '2015-05-05');
go

-- create a proc, which will return 3 results (from the primary table dbo.t on different columns / conditions)
create proc dbo.uspTest as
begin
   select a, d from dbo.t where id in (1, 3);

   select id, a, b from dbo.t where id > 3;

   select a, b, d from dbo.t;

end
go
```

After running the above t-sql scripts in a SSMS window on your local environments, start a PowerShell ISE window and run the following

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Data";
## change version=11.0.0.0 to 10.0.0.0 if you are on sql server 2008
Add-type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO, version=11.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91";

$svr = New-Object "Microsoft.SQLServer.Management.SMO.Server" ('localhost');
$db = $svr.Databases['TempDB'];


$r = $db.ExecuteWithResults("exec dbo.uspTest");

$bc = New-Object "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy" ("Server=(local); database = TempDB; Trusted_connection = true; ");

$bc.DestinationTableName = 'dbo.t1';
$bc.WriteToServer($r.Tables[0]);

$bc.DestinationTableName = 'dbo.t2';
$bc.WriteToServer($r.Tables[1]);

$bc.DestinationTableName = 'dbo.t3';
$bc.WriteToServer($r.Tables[2]);
```

Now you can go back to SSMS to run the query

```
-- after running the PS script, please check back here
select * from dbo.t1 -- return two records
select * from dbo.t2 -- return two records with id = 4, 5
select * from dbo.t3 -- return all records in dbo.t
```

You can see the following result

[image]